# Webform: File upload - rename files feature

Tags: webforms

So in webforms module, there's a checkbox to Rename files.    The File Name pattern text field.    What are some examples on what to use?

I noticed that I put in a text string "fileupload" and it didn't change the files that were uploaded.   It just kept the original file names.

Comment: It's probably token based - is there a "view available tokens" link or similar on the page?

Comment: What version of Webform are you using? D7 or D8?

Comment: Please use token to specify the uploaded filename like: `banner_[token_placeholder]`. Don't provide file extension, the extension will be programmatically taken from the uploaded file.